# What does "dump" mean in the context of the GNU tar program?

Tags: tar, terminology

The man page for `tar` uses the word "dump" and its forms several times. What does it mean? For example (manual page for tar 1.26):

"-h, --dereference
follow symlinks; archive and dump the files they point to"

Many popular systems have a "trash can" or "recycle bin." I don't want the files dumped there, but it kind of sounds that way.

At present, I don't want `tar` to write or delete any file, except that I want `tar` to create or update a single tarball.

FYI, the man page for the `tar` installed on the system I am using at the moment is a lot shorter than what appears to be the [current version](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/index.html). And the description of `-h, --dereference` there seems very different to me:

"When reading or writing a file to be archived, tar accesses the file that a symbolic link points to, rather than the symlink itself. See section Symbolic Links."

P.S. I could not get "block quote" to work properly in this post.

Comment: [File system *backups* are also called *dumps*.](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Backups.html#Backups)

Comment: @RaymondChen If you make this an Answer, I can mark it as one.

Comment: You can answer your own question with the level of detail you feel is appropriate. I don't want to flesh out my 7-word answer to a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> File system backups are also called dumps.

—@raymond-chen, quoting GNU tar manual